# Is writing an if statement on one line acceptable?

Tags: python, if-statement, coding-style

I'm not sure if this question is appropriate for this community since it's more opinion-oriented, so please vote to close it if it's not.

My question is regarding the `if` statement in Python (perhaps not just Python either) and the style. Is it acceptable to write it in one line? I'm not talking about the ternary operator of the form `something if condition else something-else` but rather when people write:

```
if condition: do this
```

rather than

```
if condition:
    do this
```

I'm confused because I was always taught (and personally believe it's better) to write conditionals in the second form. However, I've noticed that many people write it in the first form.

In what cases would this be acceptable? I couldn't find a particular guideline on this topic online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations) (scroll down a bit), *the* style guide for Python, discourages this:

> Compound statements (multiple statements on the same line) are
>   generally discouraged.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah':
>     do_blah_thing()
> do_one()
> do_two()
> do_three()
> ```
>
> Rather not:
>
> ```
> if foo == 'blah': do_blah_thing()
> do_one(); do_two(); do_three()
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If this is the case, why do people still write their code like this?

Comment: PEP 8 is only a guideline highlighting the recommended coding style. As with any style guide, some will consider it inconvenient (e.g. using whitespace in the correct way).

Answer (score 1):

This is discouraged, but acceptable. Either way works and is executed without any errors.